# htaccess redirect regex w/parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to do a redirect using htaccess.

```
http://www.example.com/design-guide/item-information.php?Part-No=8341-02
```

To

```
http://www.example.com/catalog/?page=product&id=guden-8341-02
```

I can't get this to work at all.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Rule in your `htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /design-guide/item-information\.php\?Part-No=8341-02 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http: //www.example.com/catalog/?page=product&id=guden-8341-02 [L,R]
```

If `8341-02` is a dynamic value and you want  to append it to the destination url,use this instead :

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /design-guide/item-information\.php\?Part-No=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http: //www.example.com/catalog/?page=product&id=guden-%1 [L,R]
```